# C++ Creating GUID from unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, guid, unsigned-char

I have a function that takes as input an array of unsigned char (16 values exactly) and creates a GUID (from GUID struct) by parsing all values to hexadecimal and passing a guid-formatted string to `UuidFromStringA()`.

My code is as follows:

```
GUID CreateGuid(const uint8_t* data)
{
    createGuidFromBufferData(hexValues, data);
    int uuidCreationReturnCode = UuidFromStringA((RPC_CSTR)hexValues, &guid);
    return guid;
}
            
inline void createGuidFromBufferData(char* hexValues, const uint8_t* data)
{
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[3], hexValues, 0);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[2], hexValues, 2);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[1], hexValues, 4);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[0], hexValues, 6);
    hexValues[8] = '-';
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[5], hexValues, 9);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[4], hexValues, 11);
    hexValues[13] = '-';
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[6], hexValues, 14);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[7], hexValues, 16);
    hexValues[18] = '-';
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[8], hexValues, 19);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[9], hexValues, 21);
    hexValues[23] = '-';
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[10], hexValues, 24);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[11], hexValues, 26);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[12], hexValues, 28);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[13], hexValues, 30);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[14], hexValues, 32);
    decimalToHexadecimal(data[15], hexValues, 34);
}

inline void decimalToHexadecimal(uint8_t decimalValue, char* outputBuffer, int currentIndex)
{
    const char hexValues[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    outputBuffer[currentIndex] = hexValues[decimalValue >> 4];
    outputBuffer[currentIndex + 1] = hexValues[decimalValue & 0xf];
}
```

This works fine, but I would like to do something a bit more efficient, and create the GUID directly using my input char array with something like this:

```
GUID CreateGuid(const uint8_t* data)
{
    GUID guid = { 
        *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long*>(data), 
        *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short*>(data + 4), 
        *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short*>(data + 6), 
        *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 8)
    };
    return guid;
}
```

When doing so, only one of the last 8 bytes is set and the rest are 0;
For example using unsigned char array
[38, 150, 233, 16, 43, 188, 117, 76,
187, 62, 254, 96, 109, 226, 87, 0]

when I should be getting:

10e99626-bc2b-754c-bb3e-fe606de25700

I'm getting instead:

10e99626-bc2b-75dc-bb00-**000000000000**}

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: maybe use `sprintf`

Comment: @Bodo that would still be creating a string from my unsigned char array instead of using the unsigned char array directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fill an 8-character array simply by dereferencing a cast pointer to your source data and assigning that value to its first element, as you are attempting. As you have noticed, doing so will only assign a value to that first element.

For the 8-character array at the end of the `GUID` structure, you can initialise *each* element individually, extending the cast + offset approach:

```cpp
GUID CreateGuid(const uint8_t* data)
{
    GUID guid = {
        *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned long*>(data),
        *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short*>(data + 4),
        *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short*>(data + 6),
        { // We need to assign each of the 8 elements of the array ...
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 8),
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 9),
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 10),
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 11),
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 12),
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 13),
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 14),
            *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data + 15),
        }
    };
    return guid;
}
```

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments (thanks, [Timo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6205379/timo)), using this direct initialization approach risks invoking undefined behaviour, especially if the passed source data buffer isn't suitably aligned for the corresponding destination types, because of the [Strict Aliasing Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/10871073). To avoid this, you should use `memcpy` to transfer data from the source buffer to the destination structure's elements:

```cpp
GUID CreateGuid(const uint8_t* data)
{
    GUID guid;
    std::memcpy(&guid.Data1, data, sizeof(long));
    std::memcpy(&guid.Data2, data + 4, sizeof(short));
    std::memcpy(&guid.Data3, data + 6, sizeof(short));
    std::memcpy(guid.Data4, data + 8, 8); // sizeof(char) == 1
    return guid;
}
```

Further, as the `GUID` structure is defined in such a way that there *should be* no padding bytes added between its elements, you could copy the data in one fell swoop:

```cpp
GUID CreateGuid(const uint8_t* data)
{
    GUID guid;
    std::memcpy(&guid, data, sizeof(GUID)); // Assuming no padding!
    return guid;
}
```

Comment: Aren't those `reinterpret_cast`s UB because of the type aliasing rule? At least the non-char ones

Comment: @Timo Possibly. But, if the passed data as a whole are properly aligned (i.e. the `0` element is suitably aligned for a `long`), then there should be no issues. But you're right - using `memcpy()` rather than direct initialisation would be better/safer ...

Comment: _"if the passed source data buffer isn't suitably aligned"_. I think, strictly speaking, this doesn't matter for the UB case because you're always violating the strict aliasing rule (unless `data` points to a `GUID`  object). Even `float f = 1.0; int32_t x = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&f)` is UB according to strict aliasing, even though they have the same alignment.

Comment: @Timo Edited again ... and now I'm going for some much-needed coffee! :-)

Answer (score 3):

`GUID` is an aggregate with a trivial copy assignment. Because of that, you should be able to do this directly.

```
GUID CreateGuid(const uint8_t* data)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<GUID*>(data)
}
```

Comment: Isn't that UB? In C++20 you could use `std::bit_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Also note that, although the `GUID` structure is well-designed (`long, short, short, char[]`) in regards to padding, this method is not guaranteed to work on any 'trivial' aggregate, because of potential padding between elements.